# Computed method don't recognize updated data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use a computed method `total` this calculate the number of word and multiply to a `price`.
The `price` is obtained with a method accessing an API.
But the computed method don't use the updated data `price`. Its returning empty.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: '',
    qualidade: '',
    selected: '',
    options: [],
    lang1: '',
    lang2: '',
    ola: '',
    price: ''
  },
  beforeCreate: function() {
      axios.get('/languages.json')
        .then((response) => {
            this.options = response.data
        })
  },
  computed: {
      total: function() {
          return (this.words * this.preco).toLocaleString('de-DE')
      },
      words: function() {
        if(this.text.length == 0) {
            return 0
        } else {
            this.words = this.text.split(' ').length
            console.log(this.words)
            return this.text.split(' ').length
        }
      }
  },
  methods: {
      price: function () {
        axios.post('/service/price', {
            lang_origem: this.lang1,
            lang_dest: this.lang2
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            this.preco = response.data.price
            console.log(this.price)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
      }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems I am able to see in your codes,

- Both data and methods have a property named `price`, they would clash.
- `preco` is not reactive. If it's not reactive, changing its value will not update the computed values which depends on it. You should add `preco` to data to make it reactive.
- You should use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in the axios request. Otherwise, `this` in `this.preco = ...` would not be referring to the Vue instance

Comment: another conflict is having `this.words` inside `computed.words`

Answer (score 0):

`this.preco` will be empty as long the server call ( `axios.post('/service/price' ...)` is not finished you need to rewrite this to a method that updates the `this.total` 
Something like this:

```
{
        methods: {
            calcTotal: function () {
                this.price()
                    .then(() => {
                        this.total = (this.words * this.preco).toLocaleString('de-DE')
                    })
            },

            price: function () {
                //return so that we can wait on this to be finished
                return axios.post('/service/price', {
                        lang_origem: this.lang1,
                        lang_dest: this.lang2
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        this.preco = response.data.price
                        console.log(this.price)
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```